# List all files a user can corrupt/delete? Windows7

Tags: windows-7

I had a question in the past about this [but for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/177130/list-all-files-folders-a-user-may-delete-linux).

How can I list all the files a user may write to and delete? But on Windows 7 instead of Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) is a tool from Sysinternals that can do this.

```
accesschk -s -w <account> <directory>
```

Another tool, [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx) will scan a directory or registry tree and list the permissions as they change while traversing the tree.

Comment: That did it. +1